# Subprocess program not found on remote server

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen, jupyter

I am running a subprocess in a program to compress files...

```
process = Popen(['pigz','--best',filename],
                     stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)    
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

This works on my local machine, but on a remote server I get the error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pigz'
```

Does anyone know if this is something I am doing wrong with Popen?

Pigz is downloaded on my remote

```
pigz --version
pigz 2.3.3
```

and the script above works within the directory if I copy and paste it into a Python environment.

I running the script from an iPython Notebook through an ssh tunnel described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh).

Comment: Try it with the pull path to the program.

Comment: Is the pigz program in your $PATH on the remote server?

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon to be honest I have never done that before. Would I write this in the command line? export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/program

Comment: Best way would be to specify the full path to pigz in the Popen call, as Klaus said.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. worked like a charm!